# Obtain phase and imaginary parts of a complex number without using trigonomethric functios

Tags: complex-numbers

Recently I have found that the module and real part of a complex number $C$ can be found using the following:

If $C$ = $a+bi$

$|C|^2 = C \cdot C^*$

$2a = C+ C^*$

Does someone know any operation to find the imaginary part $b$ and the phase of the complex number without using any trigonometric function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can find in general the imaginary part as $2ib=C-C^*$